# Automatically copy rows to sheet based on cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a main sheet titled **Task List** with a list of rows, and I need each row to be copied to a specific sheet based on the contents of cells in **Column I**. There are four other sheets (titled **Admin**, **Engine**, **Lab**, and **RD**) where these values need to be copied to, depending on the value in **Column I**.  Additionally, there is a separate sheet named **Completed** that where rows should move to (not copy) which contain the word "Complete" in **Column E** of the sheet titled **Task List**.

Below is the code that I have currently that I sourced from a post I found. It's not currently copying anything when I run it. Can anyone suggest new code or modifications to this?

```
Sub copyRows()

Set a = Sheets("Task List")
Set b = Sheets("Admin")
Set c = Sheets("Engine")
Set d = Sheets("Lab")
Set e = Sheets("RD")
Set f = Sheets("Completed")
Dim t
Dim u
Dim v
Dim w
Dim y As Long
Dim z

t = 2
u = 2
v = 2
w = 2
z = 3

Do Until IsEmpty(a.Range("I" & z))
    If a.Range("I" & z) = "Admin" Then
        t = t + 1
        b.Rows(t).Value = a.Rows(z).Value
    End If

    If a.Range("I" & z) = "Engine" Then
        u = u + 1
        c.Rows(u).Value = a.Rows(z).Value
    End If

    If a.Range("I" & z) = "Lab" Then
        v = v + 1
        d.Rows(v).Value = a.Rows(z).Value
    End If

    If a.Range("I" & z) = "RD" Then
        w = w + 1
        e.Rows(w).Value = a.Rows(z).Value
    End If

    If a.Range("E" & z) = "COMPLETE" Then
        y = f.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        f.Rows(y).Value = a.Rows(z).Value
        a.Rows(z).Delete
        z = z - 1
    End If

    z = z + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the loop is not working correctly. Try this code:

```
Sub copyRows()

Set a = Sheets("Task List")
Set b = Sheets("Admin")
Set c = Sheets("Engine")
Set d = Sheets("Lab")
Set e = Sheets("RD")
Set f = Sheets("Completed")
Dim t, u, v, w, y, CountLng As Long

CountLng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

t = 2
u = 2
v = 2
w = 2
z = 3

For z = CountLng to 3 step -1


    If a.Range("I" & z) = "Admin" Then
    t = t + 1
    b.Rows(t).Value = a.Rows(z).Value

    ElseIf a.Range("I" & z) = "Engine" Then
    u = u + 1
    c.Rows(u).Value = a.Rows(z).Value

    ElseIf a.Range("I" & z) = "Lab" Then
    v = v + 1
    d.Rows(v).Value = a.Rows(z).Value

    ElseIf a.Range("I" & z) = "RD" Then
    w = w + 1
    e.Rows(w).Value = a.Rows(z).Value
    End If

    If a.Range("E" & z) = "COMPLETE" Then
    y = f.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    f.Rows(y).Value = a.Rows(z).Value
    a.Rows(z).Delete

    End If

Next z

End Sub
```

Comment: @ShaiRado: What will be advantage of using Select Case over the If/Elseif loop?

Comment: Hmmm, still doesn't appear to be working. I placed the code under the "ThisWorkbook" tab in the code viewer.

Would it matter that the data in each sheet doesn't start until Row 3 and below?

Comment: @VBAPete much cleaner ans shorter code (instead of multiple `ElseIf`), but each one with his favourite

Comment: @ShaiRado, do either of you recommend different code to accomplish this? I'm no VBA whiz at all!

Comment: @user7400656: You need to insert a new module in the module section and paste it in there.

Comment: @ShaiRado: Good to know, I will look into that. I have never really used the Select Case loop.

Comment: @user7400656  Can you please confirm the steps you did in order to run the macro? Did you create a new module?

Comment: @user7400656: any luck?

Comment: @VBAPete it seems to work better with Shai's suggestion of using `AutoFilter`, although there are still a number of errors that I commented above.

Comment: @user7400656: No worries, glad to hear Shai was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `AutoFilter` method, you'll find it shorter, and faster when dealing with large data sets.

**Note**: modify `Set FilterRng = a.Range(a.Range("I3"), a.Range("I3").End(xlDown))` to the columns where your data lies.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyRows()

Dim a As Worksheet
Dim SheetNames As Variant, ShtInd As Variant, FilterRng As Range
Dim CopyRng As Range

Set a = Sheets("Task List")

SheetNames = Array("Admin", "Engine", "Lab", "RD", "Completed")

a.Range("I3").AutoFilter ' <-- expand the range where your data lies

Set FilterRng = a.Range(a.Range("I3"), a.Range("I3").End(xlDown))

' loop through all sheet names in array, except "Task List"
For Each ShtInd In SheetNames

    ' check if there is a match before setting the AutoFilter (not to get an error)
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(ShtInd, a.Range(a.Range("I3"), a.Range("I3").End(xlDown)), 0)) Then
        FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ShtInd ' <-- sut autofilter according to sheet name

        Set CopyRng = FilterRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' <-- set range to only visible rows
        CopyRng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(ShtInd).Range("A" & Sheets(ShtInd).Cells(Sheets(ShtInd).Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1) ' <-- Copy >> paste the entire range to all sheets to first empty row

        If ShtInd Like "Completed" Then
            CopyRng.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp   ' <-- delete the entire range related to sheet "Completed"
        End If
    End If

    FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=1 ' <-- reset filter
Next ShtInd

End Sub
```

Comment: The `AutoFilter` method appears to work, but the code needs to copy the row only to the sheet with name matching **Column I**.

It's also automatically copying the row to **Range A3**, but it needs to go on the next empty line. Is that possible?

Can the code run automatically every time the criteria is met, rather than having to click **Run** or **F5**?

Comment: @user7400656 did you try it ?

Comment: It's working, but it's copying the first row (**Row 3**) to all sheets for some reason. All of the other rows below **Row 3** appear to be copying correctly. The `AutoFilter` also appears to be overriding the existing filters in the **Task List** sheet. Is that possible to correct?

Comment: Is this the best method to ensure the 4 sheets update automatically based on updates to the **Task List** sheet? I want it to be a living document so that those 4 sheets are constantly updated without me having to rerun the code...

Comment: What is best? It's another method, and when dealing with large sets of data will work fast, also you are not looping through all of the cells in your worksheet. Can you tell me how does the data in Task List sheet looks like ? In which columns you have the data you want to copy to other sheets ?

Comment: **Column J** (was Column I before), contains the data that specifies which sheet the row should copy to. Rows 1 and 2 contain headers for the data, and Row 2 has filters set for every column to sort the data. Rows 3 to the end contain the data that should be copied to the other sheets based on what is in Column J.

Comment: sorry, but not following you, did you just change your data setting from your original post ?